# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac,

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-functions

My Bot ran fine just yesterday, and without changing anything, for some reason it gives the following error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.messages -> One or more errors 
occurred. -> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac, 
Version=3.12.2.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364f39' or one 
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have no idea why it is suddenly happening, without any changes.
Please help..

Comment: hve you tried to restart the function app ?

Comment: Do you have more context about your bot? How you created it, what did you made so far with it, etc

Comment: Please add your code and references that you are using

Comment: Are you using 1.x or 2.x(.NET Core) of azure functions runtime?

Comment: If you're using v2, you might have the same issue as for instance here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/813

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Functions v2, this could be the reason for "worked yesterday, not today anymore":

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/106
This also describes how to revert back to a previous version which should fix it.

Further discussions: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/46